# Using 8x8 Binary Matrices as a hash

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, binary

I had the idea of computing a 64 bit hash of a text string by assigning a unique binary 8x8 matrix to each character, and computing the hashes of larger strings by multiplying the matrices corresponding to the substrings.  In this system both addition and multiplication of matrix elements would be modulo 2.  If this works, it would have the benefit that the hash of two concatenated strings would be the product of their hashes.

This method would completely fall apart if some matrices were much more likely to turn up than others, if a large subset of the space of matrices were unusable, or if there were a risk of generating a degenerate matrix from the product of two non-degenerate matrices, causing the whole product to collapse.  As a result, I have a few questions.

1) What percentage of the space of 64 bit values are usable as hashes, i.e. the matrix they represent does not have determinant zero?

2) Given two matrices chosen randomly from the set of usable hashes, is their product equally likely to generate any other matrix in the usable set, or are some products more likely than others?

3) Will the determinant of the product of two matrices with non-zero determinants ever be zero?

EDIT: My initial idea was to turn each 8 bit character with bits $abcdefgh$ into the following matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}
a \oplus h & a \oplus g & a \oplus f & a \oplus e & a \oplus d & a \oplus c & a \oplus b & 1 \\
b \oplus h & b \oplus g & b \oplus f & b \oplus e & b \oplus d & b \oplus c & 1 & 0 \\
c \oplus h & c \oplus g & c \oplus f & c \oplus e & c \oplus d & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
d \oplus h & d \oplus g & d \oplus f & d \oplus e & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
e \oplus h & e \oplus g & e \oplus f & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
f \oplus h & f \oplus g & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
g \oplus h & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: This is an interesting idea.  Do you have any rough ideas for a hash function that would spit out an $8 \times 8$ matrix with determinant $1$?

Comment: I am hoping that it can be proven that the product of two binary matrices with determinant one will result in a binary matrix with determinant one, in which case I just need a fixed set of 256 of them to start with for ascii strings.

Comment: It can be proven.  Just look for any proof that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ and your set, as I indicate in my answer.

Comment: You do need to be a bit careful with how you select those $256$ matrices.  In particular, you want to be able to output *any* of the usable matrices.  One method is to be sure that you include a set of generators among your matrices.  For instance, it suffices to include the [first 3 here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181366/minimal-number-of-generators-for-gln-mathbbz).

Comment: I've edited my original question to contain my idea for the initial 256 matrices

Comment: Interesting.  I can see that every output does have determinant $1$. I have no idea if that will allow you to reach every det-1 matrix, though.  I think it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that because $\Bbb Z_2$ is a *field*, we can get pretty far using the basics of linear algebra.

The answer to 3) is the easiest: the answer to that is no.  In particular, if $A$ and $B$ have non-zero determinant, then $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1 \pmod 2$, which means that
$$
\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) = 1 \cdot 1 = 1 \pmod 2
$$

The answer to 1) is a little tricker, but the answer (as proven [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_General_Linear_Group_over_Finite_Field)) is that there are 
$$
\prod_{j=0}^7 (2^8-2^{j}) = (2^8-1)(2^8-2)\cdots(2^8 - 2^7) = \\
5348063769211699200 \approx 2^{62.2}
$$
You could also express the above product as $2^{28}\cdot \prod_{j=1}^8 (2^j-1)$.  As a percentage, that comes out to: $29\%$ of the possible $8 \times 8$ matrices are "usable".

The answer to 2) is probably the trickiest to show explicitly, but the answer is yes.  This is going to be the case for any finite group.  It helps to note that the distribution is invariant under group actions.

Comment: To answer the remaining part (2), the answer is that all products are equally likely. This is because the set $G$ of matrices with non-zero determinant forms a group. In particular, given a matrix $A \in G$, if we pick $B \in G$ uniformly at random, then we can see that $AB$ takes on each possible value in $G$ with equal probability.

Comment: That's fantastic.  It means that I effectively have a 62 bit hash instead of a 64 bit hash, but that's still plenty of space to make the likelyhood of two strings hashing to the same value very small.

Comment: I've asked a few follow up questions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914853/finding-prime-binary-matrices)