# Finding Prime Binary Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, computer-science, prime-factorization, binary

This is a follow up to [using 8x8 binary matrices as a hash](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902462/using-8x8-binary-matrices-as-a-hash).  Partially quoted for convenience:

> I had the idea of computing a 64 bit hash of a text string by assigning a unique binary 8x8 matrix to each character, and computing the hashes of larger strings by multiplying the matrices corresponding to the substrings. In this system both addition and multiplication of matrix elements would be modulo 2.

I successfully implemented this scheme but immediately noticed some problems with choosing my 256 seed matrices (one for each 8-bit character).  In particular, when matrices are chosen at random and non-invertible matrices are filtered out, it appears to be very likely that the matrix when cubed will equal its own inverse, causing it to become identity when raised to the 6th power.  I can filter out these matrices when choosing my seeds, but I would prefer something more robust.  To that end, a few questions:

1) Is there a way to test that an invertible binary matrix is 'prime', i.e. not a product of any two binary matrices other than itself and identity?

2) Is there a way to test that a binary matrix, when raised to successive powers, will visit the largest possible set of matrices before repeating?

3) Are questions 1 and 2 the same question?

Comment: Hi Jason! I noticed the same thing that you did in your original question ("If this works, it would have the benefit that the hash of two concatenated strings would be the product of their hashes.") but went for a design using a sequence of hashed strings and $GF(256)$ elements instead. I just opened [a question using my formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200988/using-random-invertible-matrices-over-finite-fields-to-define-the-hash-of-a-list) and I made a [Julia notebook](https://blog.infogulch.com/2021/07/15/Merklist-GF.html) about it. Did this end up going any farther?

Comment: Yes, we are using this internally for strings that act as hash keys, and I've developed both a C++ and rust implementation. Using SSE2 I was able to get performance on par with other off the shelf hashing solutions. Unfortunately the code is proprietary and can't be shared directly but I'm happy to answer questions about it.

Comment: Cool! Sure I have a few questions if you don't mind: Based on your questions, I assume you pre-selected a good matrix for each possible byte, and hashing the string consists of indexing the table of matrices by each byte's value then multiplying the matrices together. Did you try splitting the string and calculating the summary of each section on separate threads? But maybe they're too short for that to be worth. You mentioned SSE2, what is the binary representation of the matrices? Were you able to use compact uint64 internally, or did you have to split out one element per byte until output?

Comment: Mostly we use this hash for identifiers and paths… the overhead of spawning threads would only make sense if we were hashing large files or documents. These are stored as uint64s, but the matrix multiply can still be done more efficiently by processing 128 bit channels in parallel. We also frequently hash string literals into integers at compile time with macros, so runtime hash performance is less critical. Our use case is mostly a replacement for when you want to use a string as a key in an associative data structure, since allocating and comparing fixed sized ints is so much faster.

Comment: Also I learned through my comment here:
https://cp4space.hatsya.com/2020/06/14/that-group-of-order-348364800/
that there is a single machine instruction to perform this operation directly on some platforms: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/gf2p8affineqb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1).

Since $GL_8(F_2)$ is a finite group with $\alpha=\Pi_{k=0}^7(256-2^k)=5348063769211699200=127\times 17\times 2^{28}\times 3^5\times 5^2\times 7^2\times 31$ elements, for every $A\in GL_8\setminus I_8$, there is $0<k\leq \alpha$ s.t. $A^k=I_8$. Consequently, there are no prime invertible matrices ($B=A^i(A^{k-i}B)$).

For question 2).

In fact, (if $A$ is invertible), $k$ is a divisor of $\alpha$, that is $k=127^u\times 17^v\times 2^w\times 3^x\times 5^y\times 7^z\times 31^r$, where $u\leq 1,v\leq 1,w\leq 28,x\leq 5,y\leq 2,z\leq 2,r\leq 1$.

EDIT 1. Finally, if we want the order of $A$, then  we start with the expoent $\alpha$ and simply fall gradually the exponents of $127,17,2,3,5,7,31$. We test at most $1+1+28+5+2+2+1=40$ powers of $A$.

EDIT 2. When I randomly choose $10$ invertible $A$, I find the following associated orders: $255,93,42,126,127,42,84,15,127,93$. I do not see how you can find mostly matrices $A$ s.t. $A^6=I_8$...

Of course, matrices $A$ can be generated  until obtaining a matrix that has a large order. Yet, such a matrix can be very special, that is not suitable for a cryptographic system.

EDIT 3. After testing $50000$ invertible matrices, I find $255=2^8-1$ as maximum order; these matrices constitute $\approx 6.1\%$ of invertible matrices.

In fact, this result is known: cf. the Ilya Bogdanov's answer in 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109483/maximal-order-of-elements-in-gln-p

Comment: I don't think any group has prime elements in the way that OP means.

Comment: @  Omnomnomnom , you are right; question 1) is non-sense because each element of a group is invertible.

Comment: Indeed, I thought about it overnight and for any matrix $M$ you can always choose another matrix $X$ and factor $M$ into $X \cdot (X^{-1} M)$.  I think I was just seeing lots of $A^6 = I_8$ because that was all I was testing for.  Repeated exponentiation and testing if I encounter any previously found matrices gives results similar to yours.  As a result, it looks like a take-away is that large blocks of the same character will unavoidably have a large chance of generating the same hash.

Comment: Response to Edit 3: 6% is huge!  Given the enormous size of the domain here it seems perfectly reasonable to only select seed matrices that have maximal order.  I'll filter out any random candidates that don't meet this criteria.

Comment: @ Jason Hise , yes I agree.