# Using random invertible matrices over finite fields to define the hash of a list

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, computer-science, finite-fields, cryptography

> This is a follow-up to a prior question [Does matrix multiplication of hash digests admit manipulation of the result?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/91970/does-matrix-multiplication-of-hash-digests-admit-manipulation-of-the-result?noredirect=1#comment202451_91970); this formulation failed because it admitted singular matrices and therefore degenerates to the zero matrix after enough elements are multiplied. The answerer suggested using a field like $GF(256)$ instead of a ring and rejecting singular matrices, which is what this question explores.

> [This is cross-posted](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/92139/using-random-invertible-matrices-over-finite-fields-to-define-the-hash-of-a-list) from the Cryptography SE.

Consider an ordered sequence of elements $a_n$, a function $h$ that derives an invertible matrix over finite field ₂₅₆ from a single element's cryptographic hash, and a function $H$ that finds the product of all such matrices from a sequence:

$H(a) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} h(a_i)$

Define $H(a)$ to be the hash of the sequence $a_n$.

Note that due to associativity, given two sequences $a_n$, $b_m$, then $H(a)*H(b) = H(a ⧺ b)$ (where $⧺$ means concatenate the sequences).

Assuming that we can trust the invertible matrix derivation function has the properties of a cryptographic hash function, **Is there an algorithm better than brute force that can find two different sequences that have the same hash?**

I coded up an example of this definition in a Julia notebook that I [published here](https://blog.infogulch.com/2021/07/15/Merklist-GF.html).

Comment: This does seem similar to the question [Using 8x8 Binary Matrices as a hash](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902462/using-8x8-binary-matrices-as-a-hash).

Comment: This question boils down to how many generators your finite field has and the length of their cycles. If a small number of generators span the space, finding strings whose hashes provide a non-degenerate generator basis will likely be a relatively fast operation. You could then precompute combinations of elements to isolate the individual generators. After that you've got a discrete logarithm problem in factoring your matrix, but I bet factoring the matrix turns out to be a lot easier than factoring primes.

I would be very surprised if this scheme didn't turn out to be very easy to hack.